# Add a key on the fly Cloud Code Parse

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I want to add a key on the fly to an object, for example, I run a query to get the Items (class Test), next for each item a count the number of Favorite Records it has (suppose that 1 is the UserId). But, when a I call the function from iOS (Swift), I'm getting the list of PFObject, but not has the dynamic key (I don't want to save the Key on Items (class Test), because that's only to get the data on the fly).

```
Parse.Cloud.define("getAllItemsTestInstag",function(request,response){

var query = new Parse.Query("Test");
query.find().then(function(tests){
    var elementProcessed = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < tests.length; i++) {
            var testItem = tests[i];
            var innerQuery = new Parse.Query("Favorite");
            innerQuery.equalTo("UserId",1);
            innerQuery.equalTo("Test",testItem);
            innerQuery.count({
                success: function(count){
                    if(count == 0){
                        testItem.set("related",true);
                    }else{
                        testItem.set("related",false)
                    }

                    console.log("Relacion conteo : " + count);
                    elementProcessed++;
                    if(elementProcessed == tests.length){
                        response.success(tests);
                    }
                },
                error: function(error){
                    console.log(error);
                }
            });
    };
});

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just add the new key, without saving and then return it in response.success. Something like this:

```
        ...
        innerQuery.count({
            success: function(count){
                if(count == 0){
                    testItem.set("related",true);
                }else{
                    testItem.set("related",false)
                }

                testItem.count = count;

                console.log("Relacion conteo : " + count);
                elementProcessed++;
                if(elementProcessed == tests.length){
                    response.success(tests);
                }
            },
            error: function(error){
                console.log(error);
            }
        });
        ...
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I tried that but it's not received the (count) key.